# How can I display lines under a sub heading alone ignoring other lines in a file using linux commands

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file with below contents. In which I want to dispaly lines under a particular sub heading alone. I tried using some sed and awk commands but I couldn't get it. Can any one help to crack this with some  linux commands.

```
[first attempt]
a=10
b=20

[second attempt]
a=20
b=20

[third attempt ] 
a=30
b=50
```

Is it possible to display contents under  '[second attempt]' side heading alone or contents under any other side heading alone by specifying the side heading with awk or sed or cut command. The output should be as below. Thanks in advance.

```
[second attempt]
a=20
b=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -vRS='[' '/first attempt/{printf RT $0}' b
```

Comment: You should state that's gawk-specific due to `RT`. Never do `printf $0`, though, do `print "%s", $0` instead. Consider the difference if `$0` contains `%s` or some other printf formatting chars.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was helpful for me. And also I have one more requirement,  can you help me for ignoring contents under [first attempt] sub heading and display all other contents in the file

Comment: @VIJU Use Ed Morton method.  awk -v RS= '!/first/' filename

Comment: awk -vRS='[' '!/second attempt/{printf $0 RT}' filename

Answer (score 6):

Use awk in paragraph mode (records are separated by blank lines):

```
$ awk -v RS= '/second attempt/' file
[second attempt]
a=20
b=20
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/\[first attempt\]/{p=1} !NF{p=0}p' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk '/\[second attempt\]/{p=1} !NF{p=0}p' file
[second attempt]
a=20
b=20
```

Comment: You could just use `p` instead of `p{print}` since `{print}` is the default action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed` command also

```
sed -n  '/\[second attempt\]/{:loop ; N ; /\n$/p ; b loop }'  FileName
```

**Output:**

```
[second attempt]
a=20
b=20
```

**Ignoring contents under [second attempt]:**

```
sed   '/\[second attempt\]/{:a ; N ;s/.*\n$//;   b a }'
```

**Output :**

```
[first attempt]
a=10
b=20


[third attempt ] 
a=30
b=50
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was helpful for me. And also I have one more requirement, can you help me for ignoring contents under [second attempt] sub heading and display all other contents in the file using sed

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\[second attempt\]/{:a;n;/./ba};d' file
```

Match on the string `[second attempt]` and keep printing till the end of the file or an empty line. All other lines are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/\[second attempt\]/,/^[[:blank:]]*$/ !{d;}' YourFile
```

print only your section